# web.xml ejb-ref-name tag in J2EE application

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee

### I've got the following problem in my web.xml file:

```
....

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<ejb-local-ref> 
  <ejb-ref-name>ejb/StampeutentiFacade</ejb-ref-name> 
  <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
   <local>it.afbnet.printerconfig.facade.StampeutentiFacade</local>
<ejb-link>StampeutentiFacade</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>

</web-app>
```

---

At line
it.afbnet.printerconfig.facade.StampeutentiFacade

the Eclipse IDE gives me the following error:

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'local'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":local-
 home}' is expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are using the correct version of web.xml. For instance, in version 3, *local-home* is an optional attribute in *ejb-local-ref*, however, in version 2 it is a required attribute.

If it's a new project, use a newer version of web.xml declaration:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

If not, use appropriate declaration of *ejb-local-ref*.

Comment: Notice the namespace difference: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee has changed to http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee.

Comment: I'm using 1.0 version wich is the only one supported